# Extracting numeric table data from an image using Python

Tags: python, ocr, document-layout-analysis

I want to extract numeric data from an image of a table (png/jpeg/etc.) using Python. I don't mind if it's some deep learning algorithm but it doesn't have to be if there is already an existing library.

I've tried various script that I found online. Most of them are some version of using cv2 and pytesseract. One such example is here [here](https://gist.github.com/huks0/e48d604fc9dd91731bc687d6e3933db4#file-cellrecognition-py). It works for simple tables or sample files used in the algorithm description itself. However, they don't seem to work well for general tables that I want to process, one example is below. [image]

Does anyone know any other table recognition scripts/libraries that I can just use out of the box? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try with abbyy fine reader or other kind of OCR?

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific as of what does not work well? Is the code successful at delineating the cells? Are you able to detect anything at all?

Comment: @Sheldon the code at the link I posted runs without errors, not all cells are delineated. Maybe it is the grey/white/dark grey colors in the table that is confusing it? The detected output is a 5 by 11 grid whereas the initial image is a 22 by 9. Only two cells are populated with numbers in the 5 by 11 grid, the rest are blank

Comment: @LuisAlejandroVargasRamos I'm not familiar with this reader, is there a link with an example you can share? Thanks.

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: @LidorEliyahuShelef I have not. There are websites like this https://www.extracttable.com/ I'm still looking for a solution that I can run personally rather than from an external website